# Assigning configmap entries to container's env variables

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, configmap

I have below ConfigMap code which pulls secrets from GSM.

```
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: db-config
  labels:
    app: poc
data:
  entrypoint.sh: |
    #!/usr/bin/env bash
    set -euo pipefail
    echo $(gcloud secrets versions access --project=<project> --secret=<secret-name>) >> /var/config/dburl.env
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: poc-pod
  namespace: default
spec:
  initContainers:
    - image: gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk:slim
      name: init
      command: ["/tmp/entrypoint.sh"]
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /tmp
          name: entrypoint
        - mountPath: /var/config
          name: secrets
  volumes:
    # volumes mounting
    ...
  containers:
    - image: gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk:slim
      name: my-container
    volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: /var/config
        name: secrets
    env:
      - name: HOST
      ?? # Assign value fetched in configmap
```

How to assign values from CM created files to container's env variables? Or, is there any other approach available to achieve this?

I need send couple of env variable to Spring cloud config service. It's hard to find any guide/documentation for this. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Maybe I'm misinterpreting your case, but shouldn't you use Spring Cloud GCP Secret Manager for this as described here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gcp/docs/current/reference/html/index.html#secret-manager. We're using Micronaut with GCP, and no secrets are dealt with as environment variables. BR

Comment: Our microservices are not using Spring cloud GCP secret manager. We don't want to change the code for now. Focusing on deployments only.

Comment: For files stored in Secret Manager, I believe there's no other way than using `com.google.cloud.secretmanager.v1.SecretManagerServiceClient` inside your app to read the file content (as we do too). You may of course pass in the resource names as env vars.

Answer (score 0):

One of the best ways to access secrets in google secret manager from GKE is by using the operator [External Secret Operator](https://external-secrets.io/v0.5.8/), you can install it easily using helm.

Once is installed, you create a service account with the role `roles/secretmanager.secretAccessor`, then you download the creds (key file) and save them in a k8s secret:

```bash
kubectl create secret generic gcpsm-secret --from-file=service-account-credentials=key.json
```

Then you can define your secret store (it is not execlusive for GCP, it works with other secret manager such as AWS secret manager...):

```yaml
apiVersion: external-secrets.io/v1alpha1
kind: SecretStore
metadata:
  name: gcp-secret-manager
spec:
  provider:
      gcpsm:                                                  
        auth:
          secretRef:
            secretAccessKeySecretRef:
              name: gcpsm-secret    # the secret you created in the first step
              key: service-account-credentials                              
        projectID: <your project id>
```

Now, you can create an external secret, and the operator will read the secret from the secret manager and create a k8s secret for you

```yaml
apiVersion: external-secrets.io/v1alpha1
kind: ExternalSecret
metadata:
  name: gcp-external-secret
spec:
  secretStoreRef:
    kind: SecretStore
    name: gcp-secret-manager          
  target:                                                             
    name: k8s-secret # the k8s secret name
  data:                                                       
  - secretKey: host # the key name in the secret 
    remoteRef:            
      key: <secret-name in gsm>
```

Finally in your pod, you can access the secret by:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: poc-pod
  namespace: default
spec:
  initContainers:
    - image: gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk:slim
      name: init
      command: ["/tmp/entrypoint.sh"]
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /tmp
          name: entrypoint
        - mountPath: /var/config
          name: secrets
  volumes:
    # volumes mounting
    ...
  containers:
    - image: gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk:slim
      name: my-container
    volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: /var/config
        name: secrets
    env:
      - name: HOST
        valueFrom:
          secretKeyRef:
            name: k8s-secret
            key: host
```

If you update the secret value in the secret manager, you should recreate the external secret to update the k8s secret value.